# How to find next value in dataframe compare with last value in database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this.

```
print(df['Test_Id'])

0      1
1      2
2      3
3      5
4      6
5      8
6      9
```

And I can find last value of MySQL like this

```
def get_last_id_db():

    last_id = 0

    mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
    sql = "SELECT * FROM log ORDER BY test_id DESC"
    mycursor.execute(sql)
    result = mycursor.fetchone()

    if result != None:

        last_id = result[4]

    return last_id
```

I want to find next value in df['Test_Id'] compare with last_id of database.

last_id = get_last_id_db()

```
If last_id is 3 then next id in dataframe is 5
If last_id is 5 then next id in dataframe is 6
If last_id is 6 then next id in dataframe is 8
If last_id is 8 then next id in dataframe is 9
```

How to find next value in dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your index has no skips:

```py
last_id = get_last_id_db()
last_idx = df.loc[df['Test_Id'] == last_id, 'Test_Id'].index[0]
next_id = df.iloc[last_idx + 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

another option is to use np.where

```
last_id = get_last_id_db()
ids = df['Test_Id'].values
ids[np.where(ids == last_id)[0][0] + 1]
```